# Updating/Patching files inside .war in AWS Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I Have deployed my .war in AWS Elastic Beanstalk under AWS FreeTier. Application is deployed and running fine. Now if if change any file, I have o deploy the whole .war again. Is there a way to modify/patch any files (xml,js) 
inside the deployed .war in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Basically no.
You can manually access the beanstalk instances running your .war and tweak them but these changes won't persist if the machine terminates and another one is brought in her place (which is a very likely scenario)

The proper way to do it is to deploy a new application version every time you change something in your code, you can build a CI pipeline to do that for you and save most of the headache.